# Do conferences get indexed?

Tags: conference, indexing, scopus, web-of-science

A funding organism is offering to pay for the travel and stay of young researchers to an international conference, when said conference is indexed (Scopus, WoS, ...). They insist on the fact that it’s the conference that should be indexed, not the proceeding or subsequent publications.

I never heard of a conference being indexed, and would like to know if this even exists.

I insist on the fact that the **indexing in question concerns the conference**, **not the proceedings or abstracts**.

Comment: What do you think they mean by "the conference is indexed"?  Are they saying that accepted abstracts from the conference program are indexed in Scopus of WoS?  That papers published in a conference proceedings volume are indexed?

Comment: or you can provide the link for the conference to let us check it... also best practice is to check their last year proceeding if it is indexed in Scopus or dblp digital libraries...

Comment: It is the conference that should be indexed, not the proceedings or abstracts. This is the strange point that might not even exist in reality, and that I want your opinions about.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the text where they specify that the conference, rather than the proceedings, need to be indexed?

Comment: Here you go @Mark : “Besides the eventual acceptance of papers or abstracts, **** will contribute to the expenses for participation when the CONGRESS OR MEETING is ACTUALLY AND CURRENTLY INDEXED IN SCOPUS OR WEB OF SCIENCE.”

Comment: @ysalami: From that quotation, it is not clear to me that they are not simply being imprecise and actually mean proceedings of the conference rather than the conference itself.

Comment: I checked with them, and they do mean the conference. Just sent an email to Scopus and WoS. Will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a precise answer. However, the fact that **some** papers & abstracts are indexed in Scopus or Web of Science implies that the conference is indexed there.

If the funding agency wants the conference to be indexed, it might mean that some of the papers/abstracts should be indexed, **not necessarily yours**. With that, they will be able to judge the quality of the conference (very subjective, but that not's the point), and your acceptance letter is enough for them.

One example is IEEE APS/URSI. There are different formats of submissions:

- full papers (that are indexed for sure)
- two-page abstracts in IEEE 2-column template (which are indexed unless author opts out)
- one-page abstracts in a 1-column template (which are not indexed)

Thus, some submitted papers will not be indexed; however, the presentations will be made during the conference for all submissions. So, the conference is indexed, but not all the proceedings.

Comment: That is the reply I got from WoS, I'm still waiting to hear from Scopus.